# UIViewController containment orientation changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIViewController lets say it's called A. Inside A, I've added another UIViewController called B. I am also adding another UIViewController on A, lets call it C. The issue I am having is, when C is not present (i.e: not added to A's view controller) then the rotation gives me the right size, but when C is added to A. Then the UIViewContoroller's B did not receive the correct frame adjustment. Why is this and how do I fix this?

Basically when I rotate in B's willAnimateToInterfaceRotation the frame stays the same regardless of orientation. So say B is in portrait and the size is 768 x 1004. I then have a button that adds in C in A (C is in front of B). When I rotate it prints out the size of the frame is 768x1004. However, if I dismiss C (i.e: remove it from the parent's view controller, in this case A). When I rotate the frame width changes accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

I realize that I may have misunderstood the original question. But to answer the question correctly, I need to clarify what you're saying. So, you said:

> I have a UIViewController lets say it's called A. Inside A, I've added
>   another UIViewController called B. I am also adding another
>   UIViewController on A, lets call it C.

So, in essence, you've done the following?

```
[A addChildViewController:B];
[B didMoveToParentViewController:A];
[A addChildViewController:C];
[C didMoveToParentViewController:A];
```

Did I get that right? Anyway, you proceed to say:

> The issue I am having is, when C is not present (i.e: not added to A's
>   view controller) then the rotation gives me the right size,

So, are you saying that you had never invoked `addChildViewController:C` that everything is ok? You continue:

> ... but when C
>   is added to A. Then the UIViewController's B did not receive the
>   correct frame adjustment.

So, you're saying if you invoked `addChildViewController:C`, and had `transitionFromViewController:B toViewController:C`? But if that's the case, B won't get any rotation events at all. It doesn't make sense to me to refer to `B.view.frame.size` when you've transitioned from B to C. Anyway, this was the basis of my original answer, assuming that you must have been talking about the following scenario:

- B & C are added via `addChildViewController`,
- B is initially active while in portrait,
- you `transitionFromViewController:B toViewController:C`,
- you rotate device to landscape and C gets rotation events but B does not,
- you `transitionFromViewController` back to B and now view controller B receives appearance related methods, such as `viewWillAppear`, but will have missed out on any rotation events while C was active

Thus, if you need B to check rotation based logic in this scenario, you'd have to do it during methods like B's `viewWillAppear` (unless the parent view controller, A, explicitly invokes something else after it does `transitionFromViewController:C toViewController:B`). But I now realize that you're probably not concerned about the presence or absence of rotation events, but rather just that when you check the frame, you're getting weird results. But I don't quite understand the scenario you're describing, so let's continue with the rest of your question.

So, you continue to say:

> Basically when I rotate in B's willAnimateToInterfaceRotation the
>   frame stays the same regardless of orientation. So say B is in
>   portrait and the size is 768 x 1004.

Ok, I think we're good there. You continue:

> I then have a button that adds in
>   C in A (C is in front of B).

Are you saying that you did `transitionFromViewController:B toViewController:C`? The term "in front of B" doesn't make sense to me in the context of view controller containment. C doesn't go in front of B. You transition from B to C.

> When I rotate it prints out the size of
>   the frame is 768x1004.

That's weird. But, more importantly, what says "768x1004"? `C.view.frame.size`? If you transitioned from B to C, I don't think it makes sense to refer to `B.view.frame.size`. I'm not clear what you're saying is reporting "768x1004".

Anyway, you continue:

> However, if I dismiss C (i.e: remove it from
>   the parent's view controller, in this case A). When I rotate the frame
>   width changes accordingly.

When you say "remove it from the parent's view controller", I assume you mean that you have:

- Invoked `transitionFromViewController:C toViewController:B`
- Warned C that it was going to disappear with `[C willMoveToParentViewController:nil]`
- and then removed it with `[C removeFromParentViewController];`

If you can clarify your original question regarding my interpretation (or misinterpretation) above, so we know precisely what you're doing? I've definitely seen some weird stuff in containers regarding frame sizes, but I want to make sure I understand your question first.

**Original:**

See [`automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers). Seriously, who came up with that method name?!?

But that won't send the methods to the non-active view controller. Looks like you have to do some checking of orientation on the child controllers' `viewWillAppear`.

Note, if rather than loading all of the controllers up front, you do it just in time (kind of like tab view controller), this problem goes away.

Comment: well..the default of this is YES, so it should automatically forward it. why do I have to do it in the viewWillAppear? What happens on orientation changes then?

Comment: @xonegirlz I'm sorry, but my automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers was just a joke/tribute to a horribly related method only peripherally related to your original question. My main point was unrelated to that method, but rather to my notion that if your container A transitions from child B to child C, that child B will not receive rotation events, so if you want to do rotation logic, you have to do it when you transition back to B. But I think I may have seriously misunderstood your question, so see my revised question above.

Comment: @xonegirlz By the way, I definitely see some weird behavior in the container view's understanding of `self.view.frame`. I'm now relying upon the child view controller's `self.view.frame` and it seems to be more reliable. I suspect some bugginess in the view controller containment's handling of rotation events.

Comment: I've re-created the question with code sample's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415436/multiple-uiviewcontroller-containment-and-orientation I hope it's a bit clear in answering all your doubts